# How can I use console.log on IE by using Modernizr.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, modernizr

Can anyone plase let me know that how can I use console.log in my application throgh modernizr.js which needs to be openned in almost every browser.

When I tried to run it in IE 8, it is giving me an error that console is undefined.

Comment: No, my question is emphasizing the use of modernizr.js... Please help

Comment: `console` is core JavaScript class., this is not related modernizr.js, Although <= IE 8 have not `console` class. see blow answers you can handle error only

Comment: @DanglingPointer modernizr.js won't help you in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may create a simple console polyfill for IE:

```
window.console = window.console || {
  log: function () {}
};
```

This won't have any effect on modern browsers. It'll just prevent undefined console error in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the Ans, But No, I need to find a way to use modernizr for this purpose .

Comment: May I ask why? AFAIK Modernizr doesn't do console feature detection.

Comment: Nice. Mr. Michal Dudak... Thanks for the eye opening comment... your answer has been selected as the best...

Answer (score 1):

`Console.log` object is a features of some browser (Firefox, Chrome,...)

In IE `console.log` is only available after you have opened the Developer Tools F12

to avoid those errors you have to check for existence:

```
if ( window.console && window.console.log ) {
  // console is available
}
```

or you can create a console fallback to avoid checking every time writing the code below on top of you .js file or in your case before referencing modernzer.js:

```
window.console = window.console || { 
    log: function (msg) {
        alert(msg); //if you don't want alerts instead of logs comment this line
    }
};
```

Comment: I need an answer which is using the modernizr.js.. Above mentioned answer is a simple js solution... but the req from client is to use modernizr for this cause.

Comment: @DanglingPointer put the second snippet before referencing modernizr

Comment: slightly shorter `window.console = window.console || {log: alert.bind(null)};`

Answer (score 1):

You can include `console` polyfill in your page https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill which add empty function if console.log is not available(ex: IE6)

You can also try console.log wrapper https://github.com/patik/console.log-wrapper